# What do you call the sucking disks remora fishes have?

Tags: word-request

[image]

What do you call the sucking disks remora fishes have? I have read it as being referred to as sucking disks, but I haven't heard of a generic name for the organ or a specific name for the organ. Sucking disks doesn't seem to be the proper word a scientist would use.

Comment: So far as I can make out, the ["organ of adhesion"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22remora%22+%22organ+of+adhesion%22) in remora (which in their case evolved from the front fins) doesn't have a specific technical name. Nor can I find a more "generic" term (other than "organ of adhesion") applicable to similar structures in other species that *didn't* evolve from front fins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Informally, on any animal that has them, these are referred to as [**suckers**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/sucker?q=suckers):

> Be careful when handling octopuses, as they like to grab you with their **suckers**, which can hurt if they touch bare skin.

This is one reason the remora is also known as the "suckerfish".  Formally, this part of the organism is referred to as the **suction cup**, or **suction disk** (although it's actually a complex organ that uses tiny spikes to create *friction*, rather than *suction*)

Answer (score 0):

Some brief googling indicates that the sucking disc isn't actually an organ, but developed as a variation of the dorsal fin. It seems like "sucking disc" or "suction disk" is frequently used as the description for that body part.

See [these](https://www.britannica.com/animal/remora) [links](https://animaldiversity.org/accounts/Remora_remora/).

This [scientific article](http://jeb.biologists.org/content/218/22/3551) which is investigating how remora adhesion works refers to it as a "**dorsal suction pad**."